# Java Generics extends and super

Tags: java, list, generics

when I write following code I get error,

```java
List<? extends Number> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(2);
myList.add(10);
```

and I know why I get error, because ? means any class that extends Number, which can be Integer, Double, ...
so because the type is unspecified I can't add anything to this list.
my question is what's the use case for a list which can't have an item in it?
The only thing I can think of is at definition time like this :

```java
public List<? extends Number> testMethod()
{
    var x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    x.add(2);
    x.add(5);
    return x;
}
```

is that the only use case ?

and my second question is what's difference between two snippets ?

```java
List<? super Number> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(2);
myList.add(5L);
myList.add(5.5d);
myList.add(3.2f);
System.out.println(myList);
```

```java
List<Number> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(2);
myList.add(5L);
myList.add(5.5d);
myList.add(3.2f);
System.out.println(myList);
```

Comment: `List<? extends Number>` is useful for receiving a list that you can take numbers out of. `List<? super Number>` is a flexible way of specifying a list that you can put numbers into.

Comment: could you please give me a real world example ? when and how would I do so?

Comment: For a real world example of `<? extends T>`, look at `ArrayList.addAll`.

Comment: @mhndev [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/5515060) answer helped me a lot especially [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjDLw.png)